# How can I create a Class file and JAR file without main function?

Tags: java

How can I create the class file and jar file for this coding, when I compile this program its not working because there is no main function in the program. And also I am trying in command prompt but I don't know how to set the classpath? please help me
My Coding is here

```
public class NewLogFields implements ILogNotify
{
    public void onLog(Level level, String comment, IMediaStream stream, String category,String event, int status, String context) {
        if (category.equals(WMSLoggerIDs.CAT_session) && event.equals(WMSLoggerIDs.EVT_destroy))
        {
            Long csBytes = (Long)WMSLoggerFactory.getGlobalLogValue(WMSLogger IDs.FD_cs_bytes);
            Long scBytes = (Long)WMSLoggerFactory.getGlobalLogValue(WMSLogger IDs.FD_sc_bytes);
            System.out.println("disconnect: csBytes:"+csBytes+" scBytes:"+scBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you compiled the coding in wowza media Serever the jar file is automatically created in the library folder,see your Installation Library folder.Still you have problem Gothrough this link [Wowza Quick Guide](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217#startStandalone)

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do?

Create a `class` and an `jar` file out of this Java code so that you can use this in another Java program?

Then you have to compile it:

```
java NewLogFields.java
```

Looks like you are unable to compile it at all. This could be because the interface `ILogNotify` (or the jar that contains this) is not in the classpath.

You can include the path/jar containing this interface in the classpath by using:

```
javac -cp .;path_to_jar_or_class NewLogFields.java
```

where path_to_jar_or_class is the path to the folder or jar file that contains `ILogNotify`.
For example, this may be something like `./logNotify.jar` or `./log/`

Comment: ya Thank you i create .class file how to create a jar file.And how can i bind into .class file?

Comment: @Elakkiya, can you post exactly what you are trying and the error message you get?

Comment: Actually am running in wowza server ,,in my program tere is no main method so i got a No main method error.. but it generate the .class file and jar file Thak you]

Comment: @Elakkiya You get the no main method error when you are trying to run the class file via `java class_name`. You generally don't want to do that if you are running in a server...

Answer (score 0):

You can set use switch -cp or -classpath with javac command.

for example javac -cp path and name of jat file or class file yourjavafile.java

Comment: Error is print like this sir -cp is not recognized as internal command

Comment: Please tell me which jar or class file you need in classpath. It will be look like this.   javac -cp (jar file path and name) NewLogFields.java

Comment: Normally i generated a class file.. now i want to genrate the class file of above coding.i used this link for my example,i want the class file and jar file for this coding  http://183.182.84.29:90/wowz-video/documentation/serverapi/com/wowza/wms/logging/ILogNotify.html

Comment: ok how to set the class path for wowza server...its lik tomcat,Appache Server

Comment: This is my Work: 
To add your class to Wowza Pro, compile your class into a .class file, bind the class into a .jar file and copy the .jar file into the Wowza Pro server /lib folder.

Comment: i create .class file, how to create a jar file.And how can i bind into .class file?

Answer (score 0):

create the class file using the compiler: javac NewLogFileds.java
create the jar file using the jar command: jar cvf stuff.jar NewLogFileds.class

You are correct that the program needs a main() function in order to run.
add: 

`public static void main(String args[]) {
         // code here
}`

With that you could run the code with or without the jar:

`java NewLogFields
or 
java -cp stuff.jar NewLogFields`

There are ways of creating a MANIFEST file that tells java which class to run from the jar making the last line more simple.

Comment: Actually this is wowza server coding, jdk is not support because it cannot import Ilognotify. i run in wowza server..it cant find main function..i dunno how to set class path for wowza server..Help me

Comment: Am trying this link only  http://183.182.84.29:90/wowz-video/documentation/serverapi/com/wowza/wms/logging/ILogNotify.html

Comment: you're in pretty deep. The startup.sh script as described here: http://www.wowzamedia.com/forums/content.php?217#startStandalone will have a java command in it that includes the classpath that will include the class that has the main function in it. You have a little more work to do to figure out how to get wowza to use your class. Try posting a question with a wowza tag and wowza in the title.

Comment: ya Thank you but its not working...javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Comment: how to create a jar file.And how can i bind into .class file?

Comment: create a jar file with the jar command: jar cf foo.jar bar.class

Answer (score 0):

The [link](http://183.182.84.29:90/wowz-video/documentation/serverapi/com/wowza/wms/logging/ILogNotify.html) that you provided tells you how to do it:

1. Compile your class in the normal way.
2. Create a JAR file containing your class in the normal way.
3. Copy the JAR file into the wonza installation's `lib` as described in the javadoc.
4. Edit the startup script to add the `-Dcom.wowza.wms.logging.LogNotify=...` option to JAVA_OPTS ... as described in the javadoc.

   The "full-path-to-your-ILogNotify-class" is actually supposed to be the fully qualified class name of your class; it is obvious from the examples.
5. Edit WowzaMediaServerPro-Service.conf and log4j.properties as described in the javadoc.
6. Restart the server.

If you put your JAR file in the directory like the instructions tell you to, you won't need to modify the classpath by changing `-cp` argument.

Your class doesn't need a `main` method because it is not a free-standing application.  Rather, it is a "plugin" class that gets dynamically loaded and instantiated by the Wowza core as required.  The "-D..." option and the config file change tell the Wonza core *which* class to try to load.

Comment: sir i cant create a .class file because there is no main function

Comment: First tell how can i generate the .class file sir

Comment: A Java class does not need a main method.  You create the ".class" file by compiling the ".java" file using the `javac` command.  If you don't have a `javac` command, you may need to download and install a  JDK.

Comment: i create .class file how to create a jar file.And how can i bind into .class file?

Comment: You use the `jar` command.  I can't help thinking that you should have read Oracle's getting started with Java tutorial **before** you started on this.  These are really basic questions you are asking.  (And don't ask me where the tutorial is ... you know how to find it.)

Comment: sir Am using  wowza server  i dunno about that server so only am Asking Sorry... Now i generated Thank you